# Webpack - Error: Cannot find module 'node:assert'

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

Webpack - Error: Cannot find module 'node:assert'

I tried adding "assert" npm package no luck, any one have any ideas on what is throwing the error?

Comment: Are you sure you were trying to install the 'assert' package? (e.g npm install assert) Cause I see you have an error regarding the node:assert package.
If it does not work  try updating the webpack.config.js and include the assert in the fallback section (this applies to webpack 5)

Comment: yeah, i tracked down the issue to a build env conflict with netlify plugin that was manifesting this error, ty!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Please update node.js to latest versions and that should fix the issue for NX projects

Comment: updated node.js to 16.16.0 and this fixed the issue for me. thanks

Comment: Spot on here 16.16.0 worked for me too, It's a shame that the errors aren't so intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing is if you are using typescript like me, then:

`npm i @types/node`

And make sure the the `tsconfig.json` doesn't have a custom  `typeRoots` property that ignores the default types in the `node_modules` folder

Comment: that was my issue, bumped version from v12 to v14 and later to v16

Answer (score 1):

It occurs when you have an old Node version on your system and a new package is being used in your project, and you receive this error during the compilation process.

**Below Solution works for me:**

> Step: 1 - Uninstall nodejs older version
>
> Step: 2 - Install new version of nodejs.
> (https://nodejs.org/en/download)
>
> Step: 3 - Remove node_module from the current project
>
> Step: 4 - Run `npm i` and re-compile your project again

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my macOS Monterey (Apple M1), I tried updating node, using npm & homebrew

- updating with npm didn't work
- updating with homebrew showed an updated status, but when I checked
  via intellij terminal (node -v) it still returned the old version.

Resolved by running "nvm install node" within intellij's terminal in the project directory.